# Pointers to pointers and realloc in C

Tags: c, pointers

Hi my problem is that the values I assign to my pointer to pointer array within the while loop are displayed OK in the loop but are lost after the loop e.g reading a five record file (kept this short for testing) outputs the following - I am obviously not understanding something fundamental here and have read dozens of help articles here and elsewhere but the issues they address don't appear to me to be relevant. Can anyone help me out please? I know that I'm not doing proper error handling, I stripped down this code from a larger program to try as far as possible to isolate the issue.

```
Program debug output
list[0] = Test Record 1
list[1] = Test Record 2
list[2] = Test Record 3
list[3] = Test Record 4
list[4] = Test Record 5
In main list[0] = Test Record 5
In main list[1] = Test Record 5
In main list[2] = Test Record 5
In main list[3] = Test Record 5
In main list[4] = Test Record 5
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RECLEN 500

FILE *infil;
char *input;
char *p1;
char buf[RECLEN];
char hold[RECLEN];
char **list;
int c;
long arrcnt;

int readin(void);

void main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("%s: No filename specified\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    input = argv[1];

    if((infil = fopen(input,"r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error on opening file %s\n",input);
        exit(1);
    }

    arrcnt=0;

    readin();
    while(feof(infil) == 0)
    {
        list = realloc(list, (arrcnt+1) * sizeof(char *));
        strcpy(hold,buf);
        list[arrcnt] = hold;
        printf("list[%d] = %s",arrcnt,list[arrcnt]);
        arrcnt++;
        readin();
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 5;c++)
    {
        printf("In main list[%d] = %s",c,list[c]);
    }

    fclose(infil);
    return (0);
}

int readin()
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<RECLEN;j++)
    {
        buf[j] = '\0';
    }

    fgets(buf,RECLEN,infil);
    p1=buf;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every pointer in your dynamic array of pointers is the same value; the base address of the `hold[]` array,. Consequently, the last thing read into that array will be what is reported repeatedly. There are conservatively a dozen duplicates to this question a week, but they're non-trivial to find because *everyone* seems to use unique (and usually rarely related) wording in their title/body.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have honestly spent about three days searching and haven't encountered any answer that I could relate to what I am doing - often the arrays in question are ints or doubles. Could you suggest how I increment the pointer (or similar) to change the address please? Sorry for the cluelessness

Comment: `void main(argc,argv) int argc; char *argv[]; {...return (0);}` Is... weird, at best. Please, use `int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {...return 0;}` instead (or even `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`).

Comment: Thanks Bob, I learned C by looking at other people's code and I presume that is how argc and argv were defined by whoever I used as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    strcpy(hold,buf);
>    list[arrcnt] = hold;
> ```

Here you are assigning your pointer `list[arrcnt]` to the beginning of the array 
`hold`, which' s content will be the last thing you put inside it at the end.

What you want is to have a different `char[]` array pointed-to by each element of list. You can do it this way instead:

```
list[arrcnt] = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
strcpy(list[arrcnt], buf]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is excellent, I did have a malloc expression after the realloc originally but that gave me errors I didn't understand so I presumably made a fundamental error of syntax or logic.

Comment: @The_Saint your realloc statement allocates space for a new *pointer* in the `list`, but not space for the entered characters that this pointer will point to.

Comment: Thanks A.S.H At one stage that was how I thought it worked but I looked at so many examples on the web that didn't seem to work that way that I assumed the malloc I had was incorrect to be there rather than the syntax of what I wrote.